# IHttpHandler Example required for Image Type Files C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler

Can anyone provide a good example of IHttpHnalder for handling Image Type. I want to resize the image that's hosted on my server

Comment: And where the image comes from

Answer (score 2):

[Problem using iHttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385945/problem-using-ihttphandler)

and

[How to know which image has been requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385681/how-to-know-which-image-has-been-requested-caspnet)

Both have examples of HTTPHandlers for serving images.

Answer (score 1):

The answers by Zhaph and Ady seem to point in the right direction already, but if you need an additional example...

[My article on `BlobStreams` for the *Microsoft.NET Magazine* here in Holland](http://peshir.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/cool-my-article-got-translated-and-expanded-upon/) includes [a very simple example of serving images from database BLOBs](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/0/e/10e9204a-88fe-4e8b-94f6-e14497dded6b/dnm12_109_Code.zip). Can't remember if the example used an `IHttpHandler` or a simple ASP.NET page, but for the code you need it really doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 0):

How About.
http://blog.jasonnussbaum.com/?p=104

Source is available in the downlaod.

If you are resizing GIF you may also want to look into [image quantizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479306.aspx).